# How to output the value of the field

Tags: php

```
 $record = array (
      0 => 
      (object) array(
         'n_kod' => 700847,
         'wb_export' => NULL,
      ),
    );
```

How to output the value of the **wb_export** field ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can output the value of wb_export

```
echo $record[0]->wb_export;
```